# How to match a line containing only a repeating character

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having difficulty designing a regex that will match a line of text that contains 0..n number of a specific character only.

Example:
0

```
01: foo,bar,blah,42
02: ,,,
```

Trying to match line 2.

I want to limit the match to **a line that ONLY contains the specific delimiter** I'm attempting to match on).

The regex should match on **any number** of the specific character (in my case, a comma), so it will not matter if there is 0 or 100.

I've tried using backreference to no avail.  I'm using .NET for the regex if it matters, but I am not being picky.  If an example can be shown in Perl, etc., I'll be happy to take it and figure out the conversion.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the requirement, but would this do it?:

```
^,*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume for one value no comma is needed, try this (Perl-compatible):

```
^\d+:\s+(\w*,)*\w*$
```